# How to set correct path for opening pdf file by using programName.bat?

Tags: file, javafx, path, java-11

I am struggling with opening a PDF file as a user's documentation in JavaFX program.

Code works fine whenever I open it using IDE. The problem begins when I build my program and try to open it from distributions folder.

For example, this method works, when I am using IDE:

```
public void helpButtonOnAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    File file = new File("src/main/resources/pl/com/buleek/docs.pdf");
    hostServices.showDocument(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

But obviously, when I pack my program with `gradle build`, it is in a directory:
`C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\xxx\ProgramNameFolder\build\distributions\ProgramName\bin`

And from now on, it can't see `src/main/recources/pl/com/buleek/docs.pdf`, because in ProgramNameFolder there are only `bin` with ProgramName.bat and `lib` folders.

Is there a way (after building distributions) to paste another folder inside my `ProgramName` folder, put there my `docs.pdf` file, and then set code like:

```
public void helpButtonOnAction(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    File file = new File("ProgramName/docs/docs.pdf");
    hostServices.showDocument(file.getAbsolutePath());
}
```

Or shall I use some command to pack pdf file with my program?

Comment: Thank you @jewelsea, everything is clear and working now.

Answer (score 1):

Your build tool will usually place your resources in a jar. As your PDF file is already in your resources folder, it should be packaged into your application jar by default.

You can read resources from your jar file via `YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream()`, then write the stream to a [temp file](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) using [basic Java I/O APIs](https://www.baeldung.com/convert-input-stream-to-a-file), specifically the version of [Files.copy(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy(java.io.InputStream,java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.CopyOption...)) which takes an input stream as a parameter.

The intermediate step of extracting the PDF file from your jar and writing to a temp file in the file system is necessary because you are using host services to launch an external browser and, unlike java, the external browser will be unable to directly read resources from a jar file.

You can convert the file name of the temporary file to a URL string and show it via [`HostServices.showDocument(uri)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/application/HostServices.html#showDocument(java.lang.String)) as you are currently doing.

If the browser is capable of displaying PDFs (most are) then the PDF will be displayed in the browser, otherwise, the browser will usually allow the user to download the PDF to a file location of their choice on their machine and open the PDF via an external application.